# Access video data without spawning a subprocess in python

Tags: python, video

I am trying to access video data (e.g., frames, video length) from within python.
Spawning something like `mplayer` is not an option because of a weird bug which apparently exists between `mod_wsgi` and `python`.

`pyffmpeg` and `ffvideo` no longer compile, and are not in sync with the newest `ffmpeg` versions.
I want a simple library, if anyone knows of it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the bug you're seeing? I have multiple web apps mountes on `mod_wsgi` and run `subprocess.Popen` all the time with no issues.

Comment: Other than that, you could write a simple daemon that communicates with your WSGI request handler e.g. via the `BaseHTTPServer` module?

Comment: Simon, as of now I have done what you mention, but it isn't a very pretty solution

Comment: Sure, but it's IMHO the best option that's left - you cannot create new processes from within your app, and there are no adequate libraries, so you either need to create the process beforehand (which is the suggested solution), or you find or create a library. Maybe you can use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to make `libffmpeg` accessible to python? I never used SWIG, so I don't know how difficult it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug being referred to would have to be the bug in Python 2.7.2. In short they broke the ability to do a fork from within a sub interpreter. See:

http://bugs.python.org/issue13156

The workaround in mod_wsgi is to force your WSGI application to run in the main Python interpreter. This is done using:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

If you are hosting multiple WSGI applications with embedded mode and needed to do this to more than one, you would need to start using daemon mode instead and delegate each WSGI application to separate daemon process group, with all being forced to run in the main interpreter of their respective daemon process groups.

So, any reason you aren't simply using this work around for the bug in Python 2.7.2?

Comment: I was unaware that it is a possible solution for multiple WSGI applications. Therefore, you say if a `WSGIProcessGroup` is specified for each application, it will work?

Comment: Provided you start using daemon mode and delegate each WSGI application to a separate set of processes. This is the safest thing to do as some WSGI applications might not like being run in same interpreter as others. For example with Django you cannot run two distinct Django projects in one interpreter.